# Joomla article field date minimum limit

Tags: joomla, field

I am Building a Family site with Joomla 3.7.3 and are trying to add [custom fields to the articles](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields/Calendar_Field). I am e.g. adding the birthday of a Family member in a field. But, it seems like I cannot create a date before 1900-01-01. Do you know of a workaround for this and maybe why one would add this limit to a date field?

Note: I see that there is an option called: "minyear" in the [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/Calendar_form_field_type). It might solve the problem, but how do you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the datepicker popup only goes back to 1900, you can manually type in whatever date you want.

You can change the date format disabled by going to Language Overrides and changing the constant of  **DATE_FORMAT_LC4**  to  **F d, Y**  or whatever format you want.

If you want to tinker with the datepicker functionality, I believe those files are in **/media/system/js/**

Comment: This looks right. My problem was that i pressed Enter, after writing the date, which cleared the value. It Works if I write the date without pressing Enter. Just one clarification: Exactly what does the date format change do?

Comment: The date format changes how the date itself is shown on the front end. The default for the calendar custom field is 2017-07-23 which probably isn't ideal for a family tree.  So changing it to F d, Y would spell out the month and re-order it to look like July 23, 2017 instead.  However, note that changing that language string affects other parts of the website that currently use the DATE_FORMAT_LC4 type.

Comment: Okay I see. But, isn't the "format" attribute in the field used for that? I just don't know how but that is how I understand the documentation.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that you can use the format attribute instead.